# Access SQL, select all but last X char of a field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm looking for a MS access SQL function similar to SUBSTRING but not quite as the length
of the data varies.

I have several values in a field we'll call field1

The value length varies from 2 to 5.

In all cases I would want to select the values except the very last character.
So for example:

```
computer
browser
mouse
game
zip
```

Becomes:

```
compute
browse
mous
gam
zi
```

Is there such a function?

Thanks.

Comment: Curious, why do you need to do this? Your example doesn't show it, but is there a particular character at the end that shows up that you want to get rid of?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would just:

```
select left(field1, len(field1) -1) from [table]
```

Answer (score 0):

For an actual analog to SubString, look at the Mid() function. I have an idiosyncratic idea of what SubStr() should do (from my Paradox days), so I wrote my own SubStr() function long ago (it splits the input string into two variables based on the separator character).

Comment: From the ISO/ANSI SQL-92 Standard: "SUBSTRING... returns a string extracted from a given string according to a given numeric starting position and a given numeric length" -- so ACE/Jet's Mid() expression is closest.

Comment: Paradox predated SQL 92. I started using it in 1988. It didn't use SQL at all. But I did say my idea of how SubStr() should work was idiosyncratic, did I not?

Answer (score 0):

For ACE/Jet, I would use the `MID()` expression. While the `LEFT()` expression would work fine, `MID()` is preferable IMO because it makes code more portable i.e. it would be much simpler to transform the ACE/Jet proprietary `MID()` expression into the Standard SQL `SUBSTRING`.

Note that you need to test the text's length to avoid a nasty error e.g. when testing the currently-accepted answer (by King Avitus using the `LEFT()` expression) 'as is' via OLE DB on a zero-length string I get the error, "Data provider or other service returned an E_FAIL status" which isn't very helpful :(

I suggest using ACE/Jet's `IIF()` expression (which, again, is easily transformed into Standard SQL's `CASE` expression) to test for a length zero-length string:

```
SELECT column_1, 
       MID(column_1, 1, IIF(LEN(column_1) = 0, 0, LEN(column_1) - 1)) 
          AS column_1_truncated
  FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT 'ab' AS column_1 FROM Calendar
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT 'a' FROM Calendar
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT '' FROM Calendar
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT NULL FROM Calendar
       ) AS MyTable;
```